# My JavaFX file can't find or load the application class from JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I was trying to make a Java GUI code for my programming class but my code kept giving me this error:

> Could not find or load main class application.Main Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

I emptied out the code and left the base it gave me the same error. I
already had to go rooting around to find the jfxrt.jar (found it was in
my MATLAB installation)

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

so I don't know if that is causing problems.
[here is the skeleton code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEPSn.png)

Comment: try to add code to question directly not in another link, to make your question more quickly readable

Comment: something wrong in the setup of your environment - and not enough info to help you. (java version, fx version, OS?) First try to compile/run the example from the commandline (read the tool doc of java/c to learn how-to), then setup your IDE (if any) to point to the same java/fx versions that you used in the first step and try again. If still stuck, come back with more details (or ask your teacher :)